# Streaming API with languages

Tags: twitter

Is there anyway i can retrieve only English tweets using the Twitter's Live Straeming API?
It seems like using "sample" or "filter" results around 60-70 percent of non-English tweets.

Thanks

Joel

Comment: I came across the same problem. Have you made any progress on this?

Answer (score 7):

I haven't found a good solution to this, I've solved this using the following:

1) filter by lang attribute equal to "en".

2) I found that several non-english languages are still in the english labelled tweets. So, I downloaded spanish, dutch, and indonesian word lists, and checked for number of non-english word occurrences in tweets. More than 1, and I discard it as non-english.

3) I think I need to filter for portuguese as well, need to investigate this.

Answer (score 6):

Filtering only English-language messages from the twitter stream is an active research area. You could use an off-the-shelf language identification system to locally process the stream and select only messages in English. One such system is [langid.py](https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py). Full disclosure, I am the author of langid.py.

Another system I know of is [ldig by Nakatani Shuyo](http://shuyo.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/short-text-language-detection-with-infinity-gram/). I haven't had a chance to experiment with it yet, but it is made specifically for language identification of Twitter messages.

Comment: Thanks for providing `langid.py`; I've used it on a previous project! However, I think I read recently that Twitter will be providing this feature server-side very soon, which will be a warm welcome because the language identification task itself can be quite slow.

Answer (score 3):

Twitter will soon be releasing a new (or updated) attribute just for this purpose! See their blog post, [Introducing new metadata for Tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/introducing-new-metadata-for-tweets)

> The new lang attribute specifies the language the Tweet was written in, as identified by Twitter's machine language detection algorithms.

At the time of this writing the `lang` attribute and `language` parameter haven't yet appeared, however check the [Calendar of API changes](https://dev.twitter.com/calendar) to see when they plan on releasing it (currently just specifies "2013").

#### Update 3/30/2013:

The `lang` attribute was added to the Streaming API on March 26, 2013. In addition, it was also made available on the REST API on March 6, 2013.

Answer (score 1):

For use in the Twitter Streaming API, language is now a request parameter:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#language

So for English you'd add 'language=en' into your request parameter string.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter just finished it!!
cf calendar API:

https://dev.twitter.com/calendar

March 26, 2013  lang attribute & language parameter appears on streaming    Blog post   Streaming API.

The twitter API rocks!!